# SQL to automatically generate missing dates and price from immediately previous date for missing date in table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table MKT which contains following fields `value_date,stk_exch,security,mkt_price,source,currency,name`
of say 500 securities for each day (excluding Saturday and Sunday and other Market Holidays).

I need an sql to automatically generate missing dates and price from immediately previous date for missing date. So if Friday is 26.07.2013 and Saturday and Sunday are 27th and 28th, then date and prices for 27th and 28th would be missing from this table.

So while spooling the prices for entire month July 2013 I should get all dates and for missing dates eg: 27 and 28 the sql would take price of 26th.

I am using Oracle

```
value_date   stk_exch    security      mkt_price
-------------------------------------------------    
26/07/2013   BSE         BANKBARODA    565.85   
29/07/2013   BSE         BANKBARODA    585.85
```

Now SQL should Return

```
value_date  stk_exch     security      mkt_price
-------------------------------------------------
26/07/2013  BSE          BANKBARODA    565.85   
27/07/2013  BSE          BANKBARODA    565.85   
28/07/2013  BSE          BANKBARODA    565.85   
29/07/2013  BSE          BANKBARODA    585.85
```

Comment: Which RDMS are you using?

Comment: Hi, see the updated fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9fbaf/3/0

Answer (score 4):

I've used your_table as one table with `outerjoin`, as used `last_value` to insert previous data, 
have a look at this :)

```
SELECT last_value(m.data ignore nulls) over (order by n.mydate) data,
     n.mydate
FROM
     (SELECT DATA, mydate FROM your_table
     ) m,
     (SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM')-1+LEVEL mydate FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 30
     )n
WHERE m.mydate(+) = n.mydate
ORDER BY n.mydate;
```

[fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b7250/2/0)

You could use `lag()` function also , but it won't fill data if date gap is more than one., it only fills immediate previous data,

```
nvl(m.data, lag(m.data)over(order by n.mydate))
```

-***editing***-

for your data:

```
SELECT n.mydate VALUE_DATE,
     last_value(m.STK_EXCH IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY n.mydate) STK_EXCH,
     last_value(m.SECURITY IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY n.mydate) SECURITY,
     last_value(m.mkt_price IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY n.mydate) MKT_PRICE
FROM
     (SELECT VALUE_DATE, STK_EXCH, SECURITY, MKT_PRICE FROM MKT
     ) m,
     (SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM')-1+LEVEL mydate FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 30
     )n
WHERE TRUNC(m.VALUE_DATE(+)) = TRUNC(n.mydate)
ORDER BY n.mydate;
```

or little more specific: use below:

```
SELECT full_date,
     NVL(stk_exch,last_value(stk_exch IGNORE NULLS)OVER(ORDER BY full_date))stk_exch,
     NVL(security,last_value(security IGNORE NULLS)OVER(ORDER BY full_date))security,
     NVL(mkt_price,last_value(mkt_price IGNORE NULLS)OVER(ORDER BY full_date))mkt_price
FROM
     (SELECT TRUNC(m.vd,'MM')-1+LEVEL FULL_DATE
     FROM
          (SELECT MIN(VALUE_DATE) vd FROM mkt
          WHERE TO_CHAR( value_date, 'MM/YYYY') = TO_CHAR(sysdate-12,'MM/YYYY') -- this line may vary to your requirement
          ) m
     CONNECT BY LEVEL <= TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(M.VD), 'DD')
     )first_q,
     ( SELECT value_date, stk_exch, SECURITY, mkt_price FROM mkt
     )r
WHERE first_q.full_date = TRUNC(r.value_date(+))
ORDER BY full_date;
```

[see fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9fbaf/3/0)

Comment: sorry , i did'nt quite get this query to tweak it. Can you use the fields I mentioned in the query. Thanks

Comment: Could you post the sample of your data, so that I could easily make the code.

Comment: hi, i will try it and revert

Comment: Hi Ajmal,Sorry couldnt get it to work. its too complex for me to unserstand and edit it. any other option

Comment: Either you just see the fiddle link, or consider inserting null values for every day, whether its working or not. So its easy to make the query.