# Oracle SQL: fill in dates between dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following basic script, this shows me some current capacity loading in my production schedule.

```
select rl.duedate, rl.reservation_no resnr, qty
from gps_reservation_load rl
where rl.reservation_no in ('179459','179460','179461')
and rl.work_center_no in ('ALIN','AVD5','AVD9')
```

[image]

But, I want to show the DUEDATE as a date range from the sysdate to end of the year, e.g.

[image]

I have the following that gives me that range but, how can I combine the scripts to give me the result above?

```
select trunc(sysdate + rownum) dt
from DUAL connect by rownum < (to_date('01-JAN-2016', 'dd-mon-yyyy') - trunc(sysdate))
```

Comment: have you tried doing an outer join from your query producing the list of dates and your main query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL to automatically generate missing dates and price from immediately previous date for missing date in table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939705/sql-to-automatically-generate-missing-dates-and-price-from-immediately-previous)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use outer join.

```
SELECT duedate_generated,reservation_no, qty,  dt
from 
(SELECT 
    trunc(sysdate + rownum) AS duedate_generated
 FROM  DUAL
 connect by rownum < (to_date('01-JAN-2016', 'dd-mon-yyyy') - trunc(sydsate)
) d
OUTER JOIN 
(select
   duedate, reservation_no resnr, qty
 from gps_reservation_load
 where 
     reservation_no in ('179459','179460','179461')
 and work_center_no in ('ALIN','AVD5','AVD9')
) r1
ON (d.duedate_generated = r1. due date)
```