# SQL to insert a row of null values when a day of the month is missing

Tags: sql, oracle

Please don't throw rocks at me, I know there is already a couple of questions regarding similar issues (notably [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939705/sql-to-automatically-generate-missing-dates-and-price-from-immediately-previous)) but unlike that last one, my problem is a bit different. Let's say I have a subquery returning results similar to the following:

```
+--------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+
| JOB_ID | START_TIME               | STATUS    | JOB_NAME |
+--------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+
| 1234   | 17-08-01 16:15:29,251000 | COMPLETED | EXTRACT  |
+--------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+
| 1235   | 17-08-03 16:25:20,931000 | COMPLETED | EXTRACT  |
+--------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+
| 1236   | 17-08-07 16:15:27,452000 | COMPLETED | EXTRACT  |
+--------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+
| 1237   | 17-08-09 07:50:27,661000 | COMPLETED | EXTRACT  |
+--------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+
| 1238   | 17-08-10 16:19:19,554000 | COMPLETED | EXTRACT  |
+--------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+
```

What I would like it to do is to add new rows when I am missing days filled with null values except for the START_TIME column who would just increment by one day. Exemple of the results I would like:

```
+--------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+
| JOB_ID | START_TIME               | STATUS    | JOB_NAME |
+--------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+
| 1234   | 17-08-01 16:15:29,251000 | COMPLETED | EXTRACT  |
+--------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+
|        | 17-08-02 00:00:00,000000 |           |          |
+--------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+
| 1235   | 17-08-03 16:25:20,931000 | COMPLETED | EXTRACT  |
+--------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+
|        | 17-08-04 00:00:00,000000 |           |          |
+--------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+
|        | 17-08-05 00:00:00,000000 |           |          |
+--------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+
|        | 17-08-06 00:00:00,000000 |           |          |
+--------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+
| 1236   | 17-08-07 16:15:27,452000 | COMPLETED | EXTRACT  |
+--------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+
|        | 17-08-08 00:00:00,000000 |           |          |
+--------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+
| 1237   | 17-08-09 07:50:27,661000 | COMPLETED | EXTRACT  |
+--------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+
| 1238   | 17-08-10 16:19:19,554000 | COMPLETED | EXTRACT  |
+--------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+
```

I know I might be asking for alot right here but if you think you can help me it would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure job_id will be NULL, would it be a primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DSET** is just setting up the data. In CSET we generate the missing rows.

```
WITH
    dset
    AS
        (SELECT 1234 job_id
              , TO_DATE ('17-08-01 16:15:29', 'YY-MM-DD HH24:mi:SS') start_time
              , 'COMPLETED' status
              , 'EXTRACT' job_name
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1235 job_id
              , TO_DATE ('17-08-03 16:25:20', 'YY-MM-DD HH24:mi:SS') start_time
              , 'COMPLETED' status
              , 'EXTRACT'
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1236 job_id
              , TO_DATE ('17-08-07 16:15:27', 'YY-MM-DD HH24:mi:SS') start_time
              , 'COMPLETED' status
              , 'EXTRACT' job_name
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1237 job_id
              , TO_DATE ('17-08-09 07:50:27', 'YY-MM-DD HH24:mi:SS') start_time
              , 'COMPLETED' status
              , 'EXTRACT'
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1238 job_id
              , TO_DATE ('17-08-10 16:19:19', 'YY-MM-DD HH24:mi:SS') start_time
              , 'COMPLETED' status
              , 'EXTRACT'
           FROM DUAL),
    aset (job_id, start_time, status
        , job_name, next_start_time)
    AS
        (SELECT job_id
              , start_time
              , status
              , job_name
              , LEAD (start_time)
                    OVER (
                        PARTITION BY job_name ORDER BY start_time
                    )
                    next_start_time
           FROM dset
         UNION ALL
         SELECT NULL
              , TRUNC (start_time + 1)
              , status
              , NULL
              , next_start_time
           FROM aset
          WHERE TRUNC (start_time + 1) < TRUNC(next_start_time))
SELECT job_id
     , start_time
     , status
     , job_name
  FROM Aset ORDER BY START_TIME;

JOB_ID START_TIME             STATUS    JOB_NAME 
1234   2017/08/01 4:15:29 PM  COMPLETED EXTRACT  
       2017/08/02             COMPLETED          
1235   2017/08/03 4:25:20 PM  COMPLETED EXTRACT  
       2017/08/04             COMPLETED          
       2017/08/05             COMPLETED          
       2017/08/06             COMPLETED          
1236   2017/08/07 4:15:27 PM  COMPLETED EXTRACT  
       2017/08/08             COMPLETED          
1237   2017/08/09 7:50:27 AM  COMPLETED EXTRACT  
1238   2017/08/10 4:19:19 PM  COMPLETED EXTRACT
```

Comment: Definitely looks interesting, I'll give it a go and come back to you as soon as I can!

Comment: I tested it out and it works exactly as I wanted! I simply changed the dset for my own subquery and changed the selects a bit and it worked flawlessly! Thank you so much!

Comment: After further testing I realised that when the missing entry is the first of the month (in this case the 2017/08/01) it skips it and begins with 2017/08/02. Any clues on how I could fix this issue ?

Comment: @WWWubzy I just retested this routine by changing the first date to 2017-07-31 and it generated 2017-08-01 as it should. Please show your example where this did not work. If you want to include fractions of a second, use *timestamp* instead of *date*. To use timestamp in my example, just change all of the *to_date* to *to_timestamp*.

Comment: For example if we modify the dset and remove the first entry with the date 17-08-01 16:15:29, the results starts at 17-08-03. Like so: [link](http://prntscr.com/gf10qx) As if it didn't generate the results before the first entry that is currently in the db :s Thank you so much for your time

Comment: That was not part of your requirements, and still isn't. You asked to fill in missing days, which is what I gave you. I am not certain if the missing days you want filled in are from the beginning of the week, month, year, decade or millenia. You can use the existing code by truncating the start date to whatever start point you want, then running it from there.